# Using Alt+Tab in Remmina RDP connection

Tags: shortcut-keys, rdp, remmina

In Ubuntu 12.04, I want to use Alt+Tab in remote PC connected using Remmina by RDP connection. At this time, when I go full screen, this shortcut is always handled by "host" and not by remote machine, so after pressing Alt+Tab, Remmina is switched to another aplication.

Is it possible to configure Remmina to pass this shortcut to remote machine?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Try to press right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and your keyboard will be fully functional in remote computer. You will be able to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Clicking on the "keyboard" icon (which means "Grab all keyboard events") does the same.

Comment: Ha, it works like a charm, thanx.

Comment: I would upvote this twice if I could. This was driving me nuts!

Comment: I had to click-and-hold CTRL-ALT and then press TAB until the correct application was selected, end then press ENTER to change focus to the particular application.

Comment: 5 years later, this is still a great answer. I'm new to Remmina and alt-tab was driving me crazy last night.

Comment: Does not seem to work with Wayland at the moment

Comment: This grabbing feature also allows to capture special keys such as Print Screen (PrtScr) so that it's the guest session (Windows) that launches the screenshot/capture.

Comment: Sorry right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is not working for me on Fedora connecting to Win11 RDP

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I run remmina from ubuntu wsl under windows 11 connecting to windows 10 machine. Starting wsl as admin doesn't help