# Why doesn't Remmina handle sending Alt-Tab to remote computer on 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 22.04, remote-desktop, remmina

**Background**

Two days ago I installed 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish as a complete clean install.
I was previously running 21.04 & a different version of Remmina.
That version of Remmina on 21.04 would allow me to send a Ctrl-Tab (cycle through running apps) on remote Win10 desktop.

**Main Problem**

I began using Remmina (as I did in the past on 21.04) and discovered that I am completely unable to send Ctrl-Tab to the remote Windows 10 computer.  This worked with no problem on Remmina running on 21.04.

I'm running Remmina version `1.4.27+ppa202206201051.r3b9cc80f8.d84ef65add~ubuntu22.04.1` on 22.04.

**What I've Tried**

I have selected the "capture keyboard" item in Remmina.  You can see it is selected in the following image.
[image: capture keyboard]

After selecting that item I received a very confusing warning about inhibiting system keyboard shortcuts.

I found the setting in Settings...Applications...Remmina but I'm still confused about what it means.

[image: remmina settings]

I've turned that setting on & off and tried sending Alt-Tab to the remote computer and it doesn't work either way.

**Tried Other Keyboard Actions**

I've tried and successfully run other keyboard actions.  For example, I have shortcut on the remote Win10 Desktop that is set up to run when I do a Ctrl-Shift-RtArrow =>  and running the command does indeed work from Remmina.

However, I still can't seem to send a Ctrl-Tab (cycle through running tasks) on remote.

I've also tried installing older version of Remmina but that was difficult & didn't seem to work.

**Other Answers : Old - Doesn't Work**

I found this seemingly related [question/answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155769/using-alttab-in-remmina-rdp-connection), but the solution is for older versions and doesn't seem to work.

**Solution?**

Does anyone know a solution so that I can send Ctrl-Tab to remote computer?

Comment: You may want to post your workaround as an answer. Please don't put the answer inside the question.

Comment: @user68186 I just tried numerous iterations of pressing right-side Ctrl key first and then attempted to get Alt-Tab to work & it does not seem to work either.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Workaround Solution**

I needed a way to navigate away from a full-screen app running on the remote Win10 computer -- normally Alt-Tab (cycle through apps) would allow this.

I discovered that this version of Remmina will allow `Ctrl-Esc` (activate Win10 Start button - which also reveals the taskbar) to be sent to remote computer.

This is a valid workaround for my problem, but it would still be interesting to know why Ctrl-Tab doesn't work.

It is probably more related to Gnome than anything.
I'm running Gnome 42.2 under Ubuntu 22.04.

**UPDATE - Definitive Answer**

I was attempting to resolve another problem on 22.04 and I moved my window manager from Wayland to Xorg -- [see that problem / resolution here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427221/why-wont-my-android-emulator-start-on-ubuntu-22-04).

After I made the change to Xorg (from wayland), I can now successfully send the ALT-TAB combination in Remmina to my remote desktop (win10).  Everything works now that I've moved away from wayland.

Use X11 not Wayland.

[image: My Ubuntu 22.04 setup]