# Why won't my Android emulator start on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, android-studio, android-emulator

I've tried numerous times (with numerous reboots) to start up an Android emulator on Ubuntu 22.04.
However, it freezes & then crashes & sends a system bug report to Ubuntu.

The emulator never starts.

I'm running :

- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- Gnome 42.4
- Wayland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made two changes to my Ubuntu 22.04 machine.

1. Installed the official NVidia drivers via `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
2. Followed the instructions to remove wayland (and run Xorg) windowing system shown at: [How do I use X instead of wayland on 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04)

I rebooted and then started up Android Studio.
I started the android emulator and it started up as expected.

So glad to be off wayland.

[image: android emulator finally running]

Answer (score 0):

after I installed Nvidia driver, I right click to icon Android studio and ran "Launching using Discrete Graphics Card" and also I changed emulated performance to "Hardware - GLES 2.0" and eventually worked for me

[image]

[image]