# Flameshot does not work properly on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: 22.04, screenshot

I freshly installed Ubuntu as my main operating system. I was using Flameshot frequently in Windows but I am having issues on Ubuntu.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtfcv.png)

When I click on the launcher, now it is opening a small menu. And asking me what I want:
Take screenshots, open launcher, etc. ( it was not asking before )
That is ok but the thing is that when I click take a screenshot, it is directly taking all screen. After that when I click options, it allows me to choose where to select.
But again, I do not see here the flameshot features like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylVsm.png)

```
 user  archer  ~  flameshot --version
Flameshot v11.0.0 (11.0.0-2 Debian)

 user  archer  ~  lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Also previously, when I take a screenshot, it was up to me to save somewhere the screenshot, I was usually using a clickboard and pasting somewhere. Now it is just saving it as file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running Wayland as your Window manager?

Look under Settings...About...

[image: Windowing System]

Look where it says Windowing System (mine says X11).

I noticed some odd behaviors when running Wayland and then when I switched to X11 those things cleared up.

Here's how you can change it if you want to : [Use X11 instead of Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04).

I couldn't run the [Android Emulator (before changing)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427221/why-wont-my-android-emulator-start-on-ubuntu-22-04).

I also saw an issue [when running Remmina on Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423282/why-doesnt-remmina-handle-sending-alt-tab-to-remote-computer-on-22-04-jammy-jel).

Comment: ``.`.
$ sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf 
WaylandEnable=false
`.`.`.
After restart, this solved my issue. Thanks!!
But I am not sure what it is exactly. Does it better than Wayland in other issues?
Why ubuntu 22 comes with it?

Comment: I was in the same situation -- I wasn't exactly sure how using X11 would be different.  The one thing I did know is that the older version of Ubuntu I was using had been running X11 and Wayland is newer so I figured it would probably be ok.  I've been running 22.04.1 for a few weeks on X11 and all is working great now.

Comment: fyi https://flameshot.org/docs/guide/wayland-help/

Answer (score 1):

When you take a screenshot on ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS there is a button "share" that you can access the menu. Following the image:
[Flameshot Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD2Wj.png)